# Getting an object value without being able to use an argument such as ctx

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm trying to create a leaderboard with updates every n seconds. However, for doing this I need to fetch results from a database, on which I need to get the `guild.id` of the guild in which the command has been executed. The function is in a cog called `basic(commands.Cog):`

```
    @tasks.loop(seconds=60) 
    async def bg_leaderboard(self):
        db = await aiosqlite.connect("cogs/src/level.db")
        c = db.execute(f"SELECT id, exp, lvl FROM GUILD_{ctx.guild.id} WHERE exp = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM GUILD_{ctx.guild.id}")
        result = await c.fetchall()
        print(result)

def setup(bot):
    basic(bot).bg_leaderboard.start() 
    bot.add_cog(basic(bot))
```

Comment: And what is not working? Do you get any errors?

Comment: @Dominik ctx is not defined as in my example. because if i were to add the argument into the function like `bg_leaderboard(self, ctx)` it would give an error saying ctx is not defined

Comment: Are you only trying to update the leaderboard for one server every 60 seconds or for every server every 60 seconds?